# NavigationDrawer и фрагменты

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-navigation-drawer

Добрый день! Делаю приложение на андроид, решил взять интерфейс с `NavigationDrawer` и фрагментами. То есть, в дравере несколько вкладок, при нажатии в контейнер должен загружаться определенный фрагмент. Однако при нажатии на кнопку, приложение крашится. В чем может быть проблема?

**Mainactivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DefaultFragment frag1;
    SettingsFragment frag2;
    StatisticFragment frag3;
    HeroesFragment frag4;
    FragmentTransaction ftrans;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        frag1 = new DefaultFragment();
        frag2 = new SettingsFragment();
        frag3 = new StatisticFragment();
        ftrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ftrans.add(R.id.fragment_container, frag1);
        ftrans.commit();


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //navdrawer
        new DrawerBuilder().withActivity(this);

        PrimaryDrawerItem item1 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(1).withName(R.string.drawer_item_stat);//первый объект в дравере (Статистика)
        SecondaryDrawerItem item2 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(2).withName(R.string.drawer_item_settings);//второй(Настройки)
        SecondaryDrawerItem item3 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(3).withName(R.string.drawer_item_heroes);//третий(Герои)


        Drawer result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        item1,
                        item2,
                        item3)
                .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                        ftrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        switch ((int) drawerItem.getIdentifier()) {
                            case 1:
                                ftrans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag3);
                            case 2:
                                ftrans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag2);
                            case 3:
                                ftrans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag4);
                        }
                        ftrans.commit();
                        return true;
                    }
                }).build();
    }
}`
```

Comment: Если проблема в вопросе вызвана падением приложения, прикладывайте к таким вопросам стэктрейс при падении. Никто не хочет гадать, из за чего у вас там упало приложение.

Comment: Также, если вы используете сторонюю библиотеку, ее надо указать в вопросе.

Comment: У вас как минимум `break` в `case` пропущен

Comment: Спасибо, что указали на ошибки, напишу вопрос по правилам.